# Count data from last week in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I'm trying to do a count on all of the data from last week **(Monday - Sunday)**. But it seems like it's ignoring Sunday for some reason and this way I'm not getting the correct count:

```
    SET DATEFIRST 1
    Select *
    FROM Products a
    inner join Locations b
    on a.Location = b.LocID
    where b.LocID = 12 AND
    a.Created >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE())-1,-1)
    AND a.Created < DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),-1)
```

Comment: SET DATEFIRST 1
    Select  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE())-1,-1)
    ,DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,GETDATE()),-1)    When you run that you should see why you aren't getting Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using day of week instead.  I think you might have trouble with using WEEK as you actually need to calculate:

> where a.Created >= (last week Monday) and a.Created < (this week Monday)

Here is the query using DW:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
Select *
FROM Products a
inner join Locations b
on a.Location = b.LocID
where b.LocID = 12 AND
a.Created >= DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())-6, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
AND a.Created < DATEADD(day, -DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())+1, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a dateTime column in your table, you can make use of the DATE_SUB() and NOW() functions to get all the data from the last week.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE dateTime_column >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```